# Regulate 9VDC@7A PSU output down to 3 to 7.5 vdc at a 1Hz sine wave rate

Tags: dc, sine

First post here. What would be a simple way to take the output of a  switching 9vdc 7Amp PSU and produce a slow 1Hz sine type wave DC voltage that varies between 3vdc minimum and 7.5vdc maximum? Is this even possible?

This will be used to do a final brush seating on small Hobby DC Motors that have been repaired or rebuilt.

They will draw between 1-5amps depending on voltage applied and the current state of the brush seating.

I'm trying to make this more automatic instead of doing the adjusting manually like I am doing it now. I have hobby level electronics skills, and already have several TIP122's, 2N3055's or LM338's if they would help.

Comment: 1 Hz is slow for a sine-wave oscillator. A triangle-wave would be easier to generate. Would that work? Can you explain how this brush-seating works and why you need to vary the voltage in this fashion. (It appears that you need to sweep the speed up and down, but why?)

Comment: 1 Hz should not be a problem as long as op-amp input bias current is small enough (you will need to use high resistance in the RC network around). In worst case this can be remedied with op-amp input stage made with unipolar technology.

Comment: OK, This is my 1st comment on this question. First off thanks *so much* for all the comments so far.

Comment: @transistor: A triangle wave should work also if that is easier. The goal is correct of your assumption. To sweep the voltage up and down. I have found seating the brushes at a constant speed put more grooves in the brushes and commutator during the seating process. By sweeping it provides more of a polishing effect on both surfaces. So there is less sparking when put under load in the running rpm range. Less sparking means less heat, better commutation, longer times between rebuilds,etc.

Comment: Triangle wave is much easier, stabilizing the output amplitude of an analog sine wave oscillator is not easy or quick (it takes many cycles if the distortion is not extremely high).

Comment: Wow, Everyone's response on this is fantastic! One other thought I had on this question is what about load regulation? As the brushes start to seat the current draw starts to climb for a specific voltage. So the circuit will need to be able to compensate for that.

Comment: Newbie question: I see over to the right a message indicating "There are currently 02 active bounties worth +100. Seeing as I'm new here, is this anything I need to be concerned with?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be with a microcontroller. You can easily create a lookup table that has whatever waveform you like (such as your offset sinusoidal waveform). Just output it to a DAC periodically, 'rinse and repeat'.

For example, if you output a new voltage every millisecond you'd need a 1000 element table (or 250 if you use the symmetry of the sine wave).

Vo = \$\text 5.25 + 2.25 V \sin(2\pi t) \$

The maximum rate of change is the derivative of voltage with respect to time at \$n2\pi\$, which is 14mV/ms, so that would be the maximum step between DAC updates, which is about 8-bit accuracy.

One fairly painless approach would be to use a [MCP4725](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en532676) 12-bit DAC chip (inexpensive boards are available) with a small Arduino. Total cost < $10 plus the output amplifer- for which something like a $22 [OPA541](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa541.pdf) (possibly overkill, but for a one-off perfectly justifiable) should work. Set it up for appropriate gain and you're all set.

[image]

Comment: Why go with the DAC and amp, when one can go to the local hobby shop and buy an electronic speed control for brushed motors (with a PIC or AVR so you can program it) and then reprogram the microcontroller to pulse-width modulate the output MOSFETs at a few kHz. A lookup table can then be used to modulate the duty cycle at 1Hz.

Comment: @jms nice- even easier and definitely cheaper.

Comment: @jms one disadvantage is the limited refresh rate of the hobby RC PWM protocol- it will not be as smooth as the 1kHz update suggested, but maybe good enough. Seems like 60Hz is definitely ok, and some can go to some hundreds of Hz.

Comment: I really meant reprogramming the micro within the ESC to directly control the output fets (no RC servo PWM protocol involved). Now that I think of it you could use an external microcontroller that controls an unmodified ESC via the common RC servo "protocol" (1ms - 2ms pulse every 20ms). That would be even easier to accomplish as zero reverse engineering would be required, and even the ubiquitous arduinos could be programmed to do it.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I use a PIC16F1516 in a dip package a lot at work and they will let me use a few for personal projects whenever I ask(they are under $1.50 each). This has ADC,PWM and DAC pins builtin. My compiler only allows a 256 element array though. I don't view that as a deal breaker though. I could just space out the PWM or DAC updates accordingly. But what about load regulation? What about outputting to a LM338? Would that work.

Comment: @jms. I've never seen a uc based speed control for brushed motors. I check into it and see what I find. That certainly would be a easy way to do this if available.

Comment: @OverDrive  I have never seen an analog only or ASIC implementation of radio control ESCs: [typical aircraft ESC](http://i.imgur.com/Pxt7ds0l.jpg). If /MCLR (or /RESET on AVRs) is disabled and used for something else, programming could be difficult. As far as the sine lookup goes, you can get a 1024 sample approximation using only a single 256 byte array. This is possible as the quadrants of one period are inverted on the X and/or Y axis relative to the first quadrant but otherwise identical (first rising to 1, then falling to 0, then falling to -1, then rising to 0.

Comment: @jms I found a PWM based ESC with a external pot. I'm pretty sure they feed the pot 5v so I could maybe bypass it with some method. Here is a link to it [link] (http://image.dhgate.com/aktdesc_1023565210_00.jpg) What would be the simplest way? A microcontroller? Spehro Pefhany's LM358 concept? I'm leaning towards a PIC based answer. Unless someone comes up with something simpler.

Comment: @jms. Also that ESC has a digital display showing current PWM duty rate. That could be helpful to me when tuning this or maybe adjusting it for different motors.

Comment: @jms Pondering this further, the LM358 concept may be the way to go here. No coding required. Part values could be adjusted to suit changing needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that using microcontroller is fairly simple, but the same can be done with two op-amps and small RC network around it. See [this application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/snoa839/snoa839.pdf).

But, what both DAC and the op-amps can't do is to provide 5A output. For that you will need amplifier. The best would be H bridge, but this is maybe too difficult for hobbyist. Reasonably simple approach might be class B amplifier, if you do not care about distortion (the motor has large induction, so I don't think it will have any effect).

Make sure you will use fast Shottky diodes to cover for voltage spikes from the motor. Search for 'H bridge' design considerations to see how to use them

Comment: Actually, with your rc network + op amp sine wave generator you could always run a voltage buffer stage (possibly as simple as a single power MOSFET with the low precision requirements of this application) to supply the requisite 5A of current.

Comment: @student. I will study that app note further. I have never designed or built a class ? amplifier of any type yet. I have designed circuits using transistors for switching and regulators for power supply stuff. I have also built a few projects using PIC's. Nothing with Arduino yet as I got accustomed to using my PIC tools first. I was hoping to find a method that was simpler than developing a PIC based answer.

Comment: @Robherc KV5ROB. Not familiar with that concept. I'll try and google it.

Comment: @OverDrive In simplest form, you can connect the drain of a power MOSFET to VCC, the source to your load (with the other end of load tied to ground), and then feed your signal voltage to the MOSFET's gate. The MOSFET will then keep the back-emf voltage to the load a relatively stable offset (usually around 0.7-2.0V) below your signal voltage. (can be done with BJTs too. they use more current from signal input, but can hold a smaller offset voltage).

Comment: @OverDrive I proposed you class B amplifier since it can be as simple as two transistors with few resistors and capacitors around. Also, it is old and well understood design, which means you are likely to find a tutorial that would suit you. The approach with MOSFET amplifier as proposed by Robherc will definitely turn your motors on, but its a question how distorted the output will be. Smaller motor means larger sinusoidal distortion. You can start with it, see if it works to your satisfaction, and if not use class B amp. If you want even more control, look up H bridge designs.

Comment: OK, I've learned a class B amp is just a transistor. DOH! LOL! 10-20% distortion would be tolerated fine. The motors run at twice the brush seating voltage under load in use. Hate to sound like a broken record here, But what about load regulation? Will learn about H Bridges as well. Learning a lot here!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution if you are happy with sort-of curvy triangle waves. I suggest the OPA541 connected as a voltage follower as the output amplifier- it will drive close enough to the positive rail while sourcing 5A. There are cheaper solutions, but none are all that easy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f60cXR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is just a standard astable multivibrator circuit with the voltage picked off the capacitor (must go into a high impedance load). The capacitor can be an electrolytic. R4 and R5 determine the 7.5V high level and R3 (through D1) determines the 3V low level. R1 is used to roughly equalize the rising and falling times, and R1/R1/C1 determine the overall time.

If you increased the power supply to 10-12V you could use the other half of the LM358 with a MOSFET voltage follower as the output amplifier (diode across the motor), but the power dissipation would be pretty brutal at 5A.

Using 12V for the op-amps and 9V for the power would work nicely and you could use a cheap logic-level N-channel power MOSFET and the other half of the LM358 rather than the expensive OPA541.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I absolutely don't mind spending a few bucks if it saves me hours of my time to complete the project. $50 is not even out of the question as coding a PIC and project boarding it to do the task will take me some few hours before I get it tuned to my needs anyway. I will study the LM358 and OPA541 pdf's. The schematic looks easy enough, How well do you anticipate this design will handle different current requirements at a specific voltage? I.E. load regulation?

Comment: Within the current limits it should handle variations in current (say 1mA to 5A) extremely well. That's mostly down to your output amplifier and how much your supply varies with loading.

Comment: OK Good. What method of amplification do you advise? Update: Just reread the post. OPA541 is recommended. Will look at that next.

Comment: Studying this further. The LM358 really looks easy peasy. I'll probably make R1,R3,R4 adjustable for future changing needs. The curvy triangle pattern is perfectly fine. As long as it sweeps up and down consistanly, I think I'm good. If anything maybe I'll extend the sweep time to soften the pattern transition angle. Won't know until I see sparking first. Then I'll throw the output into a cheapo hobby PWM ESC with a external pot like I mentioned above. Found some that operate above 10kHz. Or am I opening a can of worms here?